# jQuery slideDown, not working on links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**EDIT**: I was missing  **});** at the end, thanks to Petr for hinting me the mistake

I have the following HTML code:

```
 <a href='#' class='button_flat'> Why Choose Us </a>
<div class='whyus'> Lorem Ipsum </div>
```

And this is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".button_flat").click(function(){
            $(".whyus").slideDown();
            });
```

CSS

```
.button_flat {
        border:0px;
        background: #34495e;
        color: white;
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding-left:15px;
        padding-right:15px;
    }
    .whyus {

        display:none;

    }
```

I dont know why the code is not working. I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: You're missing a `});`.

Comment: Where should I place it?

Comment: In the end of the script to close `$(document).ready` ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7jEMP/))

Comment: Works now! Thank you Petr

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/5Tygp/

Comment: I added that as answer, feel free to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/224130) if you want to *(but you shoudn't add the solution into the question itself).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the edited code. The postion of anchor tag is fixed and the dropdown remain hidden at page load.

```
<a href='#' class='button_flat'> Why Choose Us </a>
<br><br>
<div class='whyus'> Lorem Ipsum </div>
```

### css

```
.button_flat {
        border:0px;
        background: #34495e;
        color: white;
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding-left:15px;
        padding-right:15px;
        position:fixed;
    }
    .whyus {

        display:none;

    }
```

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".whyus").hide();
  $(".button_flat").click(function(){
    $(".whyus").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TTukV/1/)**
Hope this helps

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close `$(document).ready`, add `});` to the end of the script and it'll work just fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button_flat").click(function () {
        $(".whyus").slideDown();
    });
});
```

#### [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7jEMP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href='#' class='button_flat'> Why Choose Us </a>
 <div class='whyus' style="display:none;"> Lorem Ipsum </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".button_flat").click(function () {
    $(".whyus").slideDown();
 });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wACdg/1/)

Comment: I already have that in my CSS, I made a edit and included the CSS in my question

Comment: When i create Demo your edit is not posted that time.For clearity please view Demo

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot `});` at the end of jquery. I recommend using `toggle`, so when you have the .whyus div displayed, clicking again on button will slide it up.

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TTukV/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button_flat").click(function(){
    $(".whyus").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `return false;` anchor click event to prevent it from opening link that's in href="#".
And before `.slideDown(duration);` animation must stop and hide then animate it again.

Html:

```
 <a href='#' class='button_flat'> Why Choose Us </a>
 <div class='whyus'> Lorem Ipsum </div>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".button_flat").click(function () {
     $(".whyus").stop().hide().slideDown();
     return false;
  });
});
```

Css:

```
.button_flat {
  border:0px;
  background: #34495e;
  color: white;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
}
.whyus {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add event.preventDefault(); at the end of click listener function, to stop default click behavior continued by browser.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button_flat").click(function(){
      $(".whyus").slideDown();
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: I would like to know the reason for negative vote. I suggested coding solution, syntax error should be corrected by coder.

Answer (score -1):

Add event.preventDefault();

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
$(".button_flat").click(function(){
  $(".whyus").slideDown();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

});